# Clone and edit an object with inlineformset factory

Tags: django, inline-formset

I have three models, viz. Item, RecipeIngredient and Recipe which look like this:

Model - RecipeIngredient

```
class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    item_quant = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    sub_recipe = models.ForeignKey(
       Recipe, blank=True, null=True,
       related_name="sub_recipe"
    )

    class Meta:
       verbose_name = _("Recipe Ingredient")
       verbose_name_plural = _("Recipe Ingredients")
       unique_together = (('item', 'recipe'),)
```

Model - Recipe

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=128,
    )
    num_servings = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
       verbose_name = 'Recipe'
       verbose_name_plural = 'Recipies'
```

Model - Item

```
    class Item(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(
            max_length=128
        )
```

I have RecipeCreateView where I am using inlineformset_factory to create the recipe and the corresponding ingredients.

I have a functionality in the RecipeListView to clone the recipe.
What I am doing here is that I am redirecting to the create view url with the id of the recipe to be cloned.

RecipeCreateView -

```
    class RecipeCreateView(InventoryEditMixin, CreateView):
        model = Recipe
        form_class = RecipeForm
        template_name = 'inventory/recipe_add.html'
        formset_class = RecipeIngredientFormSet

        def get_initial(self):
        clone_recipe = self.request.GET.get('clone_recipe')
        if clone_recipe:
            recipe = Recipe.objects.filter(id=clone_recipe).first()
            if recipe:
                self.initial.update({'num_servings': recipe.num_servings})

        return self.initial
```

Under `InventoryEditMixin`, I am using get_context_data to initialize the inlineformset_factory using the queryset.

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        clone_recipe = self.request.GET.get('clone_recipe')
        if clone_recipe:
            recipe = Recipe.objects.get(id=clone_recipe)
            ingredients = RecipeIngredient.objects.filter(
                recipe__id=clone_recipe)
            if recipe:
                context['formset'] = RecipeIngredientFormSet(
                    queryset=ingredients,
                )

        return context
```

This is not initializing the formset. Not able to figure out why.

By the way, my inlineformset_factory looks like this:

```
    RecipeIngredientFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
        Recipe,
        RecipeIngredient,
        fk_name='recipe',
        form=RecipeIngredientForm,
        formset=BaseRecipeFormSet,
        can_order=False,
        can_delete=True, extra=1,
        fields=('id',
                'item',
                'item_quant'))
```

Any idea, how do I initialize?

Comment: it's darn hard to use formsets with CBVs

Comment: Achieved it in a different way. Saved a new object by resetting pk and then redirecting to edit page(UpdateView) with that pk.